# Counting all the matchings of a pattern in a vector in R

Tags: r, pattern-matching, boolean-expression

I have a boolean vector in which I want to count the number of occurrences of some patterns.

For example, for the pattern `"(1,1)"` and the vector `"(1,1,1,0,1,1,1)"`, the answer should be 4.

The only built-in function I found to help is `grepRaw`, which finds the occurrences of a particular string in a longer string. However, it seems to fail when the sub-strings matching the pattern overlap:

```
length(grepRaw("11","1110111",all=TRUE))
# [1] 2
```

Do you have any ideas to obtain the right answer in this case?

**Edit 1**

I'm afraid that Rich's answer works for the particular example I posted, but fails in a more general setting:

`> sum(duplicated(rbind(c(FALSE,FALSE),embed(c(TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE),2))))
[1] 3`

In this other example, the expected answer would be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the function `rollapply` you can apply a moving window of `width = 2` summing the values. Then you can sum the records where the result is equal to 2 i.e. `sum(c(1,1))`

```
 library(zoo)

 z <- c(1,1,1,0,1,1,1)
 sum(rollapply(z, 2, sum) == 2)
```